# Multiple kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-helm, kops, kubernetes-cluster

The requirement is, for each new build for QA should create a new kubernetes cluster (new enviroment altogether) and then it should be destroyed after QA is completed.
So it is not a federated setup.

I am using `kops` in AWS to create cluster.

Do I need to create another 'bootstrap' instance for creating new cluster? The guess is I can change the name of cluster in command and it will create a new cluster. Like `kops create cluster --zones=<zones> <some-other-name>`.

So question is what does `kubectl get all` return - consolidated objects?

When I do `kubectl apply -f .`, how doest kubectl know which cluster to apply to?

How do I specify cluster name while installing things like `helm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be setting the context on your cluster something like this, once this is set then all your kubectl commands will be run in the context of that cluster.

`kubectl config use-context my-cluster-name`

Refer this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#kubectl-context-and-configuration) for more details

Comment: In case of using kops, the s3 bucket needs to be saved too.
Following command will do

`export KOPS_STATE_STORE=s3://<name of bucket here>`